# Performance costs of casting a concrete collection to its interface

Tags: java, performance, casting

When I write some API, it sometimes will use `Collection<Model>` to be the parameter. Of course, you can use `ArrayList` if you know `ArrayList` is already enough to handle all the use case.

My question is is there any considerable performance cost when for example cast the `ArrayList<Model>` to `Collection<Model>` when passing parameter.

Will the collection size also impact the performance of casting? Any advice?

Thanks for Peter's answer.

I think the answer is pretty enough to stop me to waste time on changing it.

**EDIT**

As said in accepted answer, the cost is actually paid in the calling of interface methods.
it's not free to keep this kind of flexibity. But the cost is not so considerable.

Comment: You cannot cast a `Collection<Model>` to a `Collection<IModel>` (assuming `Model` extends/implements `IModel`).

Comment: I'm assuming you haven't done some performance test.

Comment: I just want to hear some advice to see if it's really to be worthy of changing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most performance questions the answer is; write cleare and simple code and the application usually performs okay as well.

A cast to an interface can take around 10 ns (less than a method call) Depending on how the code is optimised, it might be too small to measure.

A cast between generic types is a compiler time check, nothing actually happens at runtime.

When you cast, it is the reference type which changes, all references are the same size. The size of what they point to doesn't matter.

BTW: All ArrayList objects are the same size, All LinkedList objects are the same size all HashMap objects are the same size etc. They can reference an array which can be different sizes in different collection.

---

You can see a difference in code which hasn't been JITed.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
  ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i=0;i<100;i++) ints.add(i);
  sumSize(ints, 5000);
  castSumSize(ints, 5000);
  sumSize(ints, 5000);
  castSumSize(ints, 5000);
}

public static long sumSize(ArrayList<Integer> ints, int runs) {
  long sum = 0;
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  for(int i=0;i<runs;i++)
    sum += ints.size();
  long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
  System.out.printf("sumSize: Took an average of %,d ns%n", time/runs);
  return sum;
}

public static long castSumSize(ArrayList<Integer> ints, int runs) {
  long sum = 0;
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  for(int i=0;i<runs;i++)
    sum += ((Collection) ints).size();
  long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
  System.out.printf("castSumSize: Took an average of %,d ns%n", time/runs);
  return sum;
}
```

prints

```
sumSize: Took an average of 31 ns
castSumSize: Took an average of 37 ns
sumSize: Took an average of 28 ns
castSumSize: Took an average of 34 ns
```

however the difference is likely to be due to the method calls being more expensive.  The only bytecode difference is

```
invokevirtual   #9; //Method java/util/ArrayList.size:()I
```

and

```
invokeinterface #15,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/Collection.size:()I
```

Once the JIT has optimised the code there isn't much difference. Run long enough, the time drops to 0 ns for the *-server* JVM because it detects the loop doesn't do anything. ;)

Comment: With regards to the 10ns figure, what is it that actually needs to happen at runtime when an instance of `ArrayList<T>` is cast to `Collection<T>`? Is this not an entirely compile-time operation?

Comment: A cast between generic types is a compiler time check, nothing actually happens at runtime. Nice answer!

Comment: @aix, Good question. I will do some tests to see what happens or if this is just error in benchmarks. Or an extra cost in method calls using it. (Assigning it and not using will get removed from the JIT native code)

Comment: @aix, its also tricky to write code the JIT doesn't eliminate. ;)

Comment: @aix, you are right that the cast itself is eliminated by the compiler. However, unless you use the reference, it is discarded completely. i.e. you have to use it to be meaningful. That usage is more expensive for an interface reference. Once it is JITed it might not matter (see above)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Nice, thanks for taking the time to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Compared to doing *anything* with any object: absolutely none.

And even if it did, be sure any program involves things taking *millions* more time!

Comment: I see no conflict myself! He says it takes no time at runtime, and I say the same thing, especially compared to the overall execution time!

Comment: He says "A cast to an interface can take around 10 ns".  That's not no time.

Answer (score 0):

Collection is an [interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html). You always have to provide a concrete [implementation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html) such as ArrayList.

Commonly it would be this

```
Collection<Model> myCollection = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

Designing to interfaces is actually good practice, so use Collection as your method parameter.

Comment: Yes, the OP knows that.  He's asking what happens when you cast the concrete collection down to the interface collection.